# First character of table column name in upper case

Tags: gui-design, tables, guidelines, human-interface-guideline, formatting

I have a table with the following column descriptions.:

```
|   Titel    | bisheriges Ablaufdatum | neues Ablaufdatum |
|:-----------|-----------------------:|:-----------------:|
|   First    |      10.12.2015        |     10.12.2018    |
```

Is it good practice to have an upper case letter for the first character of the table column name in the GUI?

So instead of `bisheriges Ablaufdatum` better `Bisheriges Ablaufdatum`?

```
|   Titel    | Bisheriges Ablaufdatum | Neues Ablaufdatum |
|:-----------|-----------------------:|:-----------------:|
|   First    |      10.12.2015        |     10.12.2018    |
```

I think it looks nicer if the first letter is uppercase.

Maybe it is irrelevant? Is there a common pratice for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In English it is standard practice to capitalize each word in a heading. It looks "wrong" to native English readers. However this is not necessarily the case in other languages.

If your target audience are English speakers then the answer is a clear-cut yes. Capitalize Each Word. (There are exceptions but this works as a general rule.)

> Here is what to capitalize:
>
> - All words of four or more letters, no matter what or where the words
>     are (more on this rule later)
> - The first word of the title and of the
>     subtitle
> - The last word of the title
> - ALL OTHER WORDS except
>     conjunctions (and, or, but, nor, yet, so, for), articles (a, an, the),
>     and short prepositions (in, to, of, at, by, up, for, off, on).
>
> The Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications does not
>   capitalize four-letter prepositions.
>
> The Chicago Manual of Style
>   (Chicago) and The MLA Handbook don't capitalize any
>   prepositions--unless, for all three manuals, the word fits in category
>   2 or 3 above.

Comment: Just an example to make sure I understood the rules correctly: "Why Are Good Answers on StackExchange Hard to Come By?"

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - Perfect.